# Remove the last element from an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to remove the last entry in my array, and I want the array to show me that it has 1 less entry when I am using the `${#array[@]}`. This is the current line I am using:

```
unset GreppedURLs[${#GreppedURLs[@]} -1]
```

Please correct me and show me the right way.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The answer you have is (nearly) correct [for non-sparse indexed arrays](http://web.archive.org/web/20230316102937/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays)¹:

```
unset 'arr[${#arr[@]}-1]'
```

> Bash 4.3 or higher added this new syntax to do the same:

> ```
>  unset arr[-1]
> ```

(Note the single quotes: they prevent pathname expansion).

Demo:

```bash
arr=( a b c )
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

> 3

```
for a in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done
```

> ```
> a
> b
> c
> ```

```
unset 'arr[${#arr[@]}-1]'
for a in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done
```

> ```
> a
> b
> ```

**Punchline**

```
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

(GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))

---

¹ @Wil provided an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327243) that works for all kinds of arrays

Comment: Works in GNU bash, version 3.1.0(3)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.9)

Comment: @Wil I'd disagree with the repeated "wrong" and "fundamentally wrong" etc. Your answer is solid, and you get a +1 for it. This answer is not "wrong", it's less generic. I'd say nothing in the original question suggested associative arrays. Not to mention that when the question was posed Bash 4 was very much a rarity. I'd gladly hand your answer the Accept if I could, because your answer is way more up-to-date. I'd appreciate if you reconsidered all the unnecessary competitive rhetorics though.

Comment: @sehe The data set for the original question isn't provided, that's why I said your answer is wrong - because it makes blind assumptions about the data set... if you want to call my comments "competitive rhetorics", well, lol... you're entitled to look like you do speaking like that.

Comment: Would using double-quotes here be equivalent?

Comment: Of course it is needless to ruin readability of your code by writing that index monster `arr[${#arr[@]}-1]`. Bash arrays can be thought of as 'circular' structures, that is, -1st item is the same as the last item. Hence `unset arr[-1]`.

Comment: @GézaTörök "Of course" that feature was copied from zsh. It's nice but realize that was added in bash 4.3 (several years after this answer was written). Not every system has a recent bash. E.g. Ubuntu LTS barely has it (4.4). Updated answer text

Comment: @sehe thanks for pointing this one out. (Sadly I cannot edit my comment anymore)

Comment: I would very much like to emphasize the importance of the answer's note: use the variable in quotes to avoid pathname expansion! And to further clarify, the brackets [] are special glob characters (depending of course to your bash glob options, e.g. in a script vs in interactive mode).

Answer (score 16):

You must remove the blank before `-1`.

Answer (score 14):

If you'd like an answer which won't eat your kittens, try this:

```
array=([1]=1 {2..5} [10]=6);
# declare -a array='([1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [10]="6}")'
index=("${!array[@]}");
# declare -a index='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="10")'
unset 'array[${index[@]: -1}]';
# declare -a array='([1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5")'
```

And there you have it - removing the last element.  Now I'll present a much easier answer which probably meets your needs but has a caveat:

```
array=([1]=1 {2..5} [10]=6);
# declare -a array='([1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [10]="6}")'
array=("${array[@]::${#array[@]}-1}");
# declare -a array='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")'
```

This version takes a shortcut.  It re-indexes the array and drops the last element.  Unfortunately you can also see that the index has not been maintained.  The values and their order has been.  If you don't care about the index then this is probably the answer you wanted.

Both of the above answers will also work on [bash 4 Associative Arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#associative_bash_4).

--

The chosen answer is not safe. Here's an example:

```
array=([1]=1 {2..5} [10]=6);
# declare -a array='([1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [10]="6")'
unset 'arr[${#arr[@]}-1]';
# declare -a array='([1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [10]="6")'
```

Okay so as you can see it is unsetting the element with index 5 because it incorrectly calculated the index of the last element of the array. It failed because it operated on an assumption that all arrays are zero-based, and not sparse.  This answer will fail on arrays starting with anything other than zero, arrays which are sparse, and obviously must fail for an associative array with 'fubar' for the last element.

Comment: The standard way in Bash≥4 is to just use `unset 'arr[-1]'`. By the way, your answer is also wrong: you're missing quotes in your `unset` statements, so your command is subject to pathname expansion.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Does that DoTheRightThing for associative arrays? That would be the slam-down answer

Comment: @sehe: of course it doesn't work as expected for associative arrays (it will unset the field with key `-1`). But that's not really an issue: it doesn't really make sense (read: it's not useful) to remove the “last” element of an associative array; what is the “last” element in the case of an associative array?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that's actually a nice point; Indeed [bash's associative arrays are unordered](http://ngeiswei.blogspot.nl/2012/03/another-bash-weirdness-associative.html). Of course the unspecified order is deterministic - so you /could/ show the list to a user and claim it's useful to have the user "delete the last entry shown". But that's pretty contrived. Thanks for making me think it through.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf TY for the pointer re: quoting the unset argument. To answer your question about the usefulness of removing the last element of an assoc array -  what if you want to pop key/value pairs off a list?  You're right about the order not being maintained but that doesn't stop it from being useful.

Comment: For people not getting it, I think @Wil's comment is in reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247433/remove-the-last-element-from-an-array/41327243#comment69867437_8247497). I appreciate all the good thinking and information here.

Comment: How about you quote the array expansion to populate `index`? You claim your method doesn't eat my kittens but it does. `declare -A array=( [\*]=you_killed_my_kittens [cat]=i_love_kittens ); index=(${!array[@]}); unset 'array[${index[@]: -1}]'; declare -p array`. Boooooh!

Answer (score 9):

For any indexed array (sparse or not), since bash 4.3+ (and ksh93+), this is the simplest of solutions:

```
unset 'array[-1]'
```

The quotes are needed to avoid shell expansion in bash if the -1 is an arithmetic expression or a variable. This also works correctly:

```
a=3; unset 'arr[ a - 4 * 1 ]'
```

But will not work if unquoted (`''`) as the * will be expanded to the list of files in the present working directory (`$pwd`).

For older bash versions: this works since bash 3.0 for non-sparse arrays:

```
unset 'arr[ ${#arr[@]}-1 ]'
```

Example:

```
$ arr=( {a..i} ); declare -p arr  
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [7]="h")
$ unset 'arr[ ${#arr[@]}-1 ]'; declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g")
```

This will **not** work for sparse arrays (with some holes):

```
$ arr=( {a..g} [9]=i ); declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [9]="i")
$ unset 'arr[ ${#arr[@]}-1 ]'; declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [9]="i")
```

This happens because the count of elements (`${#arr[@]}`) is `8` and `8-1` is `7`.
So, the command will unset `arr[7]`, which doesn't exist. Nothing is done.

A solution, that also work for Associative arrays (in whatever it could mean "the last element" in an unsorted list) is to generate a new array of indexes.
Then use the last index to unset that element.

Assuming `arr` is already defined (for bash 3.0+):

```
$ index=( "${!arr[@]}" )          # makes index non-sparse.
$ unset 'arr[${index[@]}-1]'      # unset the last index.
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g")
```

A slightly more portable (works in ksh93), that looks ugly, solution is:

```
$ arr=( {a..e} [9]=i )
$ index=( "${!arr[@]}" )
$ unset "arr[  ${index[${#index[@]}-1]}  ]"   # Yes, double quotes.
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e")
```

Or (again, double quotes for ksh):

```
$ unset "arr[${index[@]: -1}]"
```

If you want to avoid the space and the negative number, make it a variable:

```
$ a="-1"; unset "arr[${index[@]:a}]"
```

Comment: I like the terseness of `unset 'array[-1]'`, but sadly it is not a valid command in bash v4, which is the most recent version available for my OS. I'll keep it in mind for the future, though.

Comment: @CameronHudson Then use `unset 'array[${index[@]}-1]'` since bash 3.0 (which is listed inside this answer).

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for Mac/bash@3.x and Linux (ubuntu/bash@4.x)

```
unset arr[$[${#arr[@]}-1]] # non-sparse array only
```

in more details:

```
len=${#arr[@]}
idx=$[$len-1]    # <=> $(($len-1))
unset arr[$idx]
```

Comment: The `$[ ]` syntax is deprecated.

Comment: working case for GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you could add the following:

```
target="${@:$(($#)):1}"
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
```