# Access second func param when first param is an array in Bash

Tags: bash

If I have a bash function with two or more params, and the first is an array, how can I access the second param?

It's the same as this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992439/bash-pass-both-array-and-non-array-parameter-to-function) but the non-array param is the first argument there, while mine is not (so it does not answer my question).

```
function getParam() {
   arr=("$@")
   for i in "${arr[@]}";
   do
      echo $i #works - print array item
   done

   var=$2
   echo $var #not working - returns two; I want 3
}

array=('one' 'two' 'three')

getParam "${array[@]}" 3
```

Comment: That *doesn't* pass the array as the first parameter. It passes *each element in the array* as a separate parameter -- which is all you *can* do, since arguments are by nature strings.

Comment: ...so the easy answer is to change your calling convention to put the non-array argument *first*, as in the linked answer.

Comment: ...and the less-easy answer is to pass the array by name rather than by value, for which we have plenty of duplicates already in the knowledge base.

Comment: But I don't have access to change the order.

Comment: If you can't change the caller (and can only change the function definition), then you can't change to pass-by-name either, so what you're asking us to do is take everything but the last entry in your argument list into an array, and treat the last argument as a separate value. That's doable, and I'd have to look to see if there are duplicates for it.

Comment: Note that `bash` doesn't have array *values* at all. Setting the array attribute on a *name* provides additional syntax for indexing the *simulates* an array value. Note that `$array` and `${array[0]}` expand to exactly the same thing, whether or not the array attribute is set on the name `array`.

Comment: BTW, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: `echo $i` and `echo $var`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass arrays to functions in bash. You can only pass strings.

Any arrays passed with `"${array[@]}"` will expand to multiple parameters (similar to the "splat" operator in some languages). This:

```
getParam "${array[@]}" 3
```

Is therefore equivalent to this:

```
getParam "one" "two" "three" 3
```

Explaining why `$2` is `two`

Instead, you can:

- [Move the parameter in front](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992439/bash-pass-both-array-and-non-array-parameter-to-function) like most other tools do
- [Get the last parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script) instead of the second one
- [Pass arrays by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953833/passing-multiple-distinct-arrays-to-a-shell-function), and passing the name as a single string

Comment: [remove the last element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247433/remove-the-last-element-from-an-array) might be an additional element of the "get the last parameter" solution.

Comment: I think getting the last param is going to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What you *can* do here is use a couple of tricky parameter expansions:

```
getparams() {
    local ary=( "${@:1:$#-1}" )
    local last=${!#}
    declare -p ary last
}

getparams "a b" "c d" 10
```

```
declare -a ary='([0]="a b" [1]="c d")'
declare -- last="10"
```

`ary` is taking a slice of the positional parameters, starting with index 1 and taking ($# - 1) = (3 - 1) = 2 elements.
`last` is variable indirection: `$#` here is 3, so `${!#}` is equivalent to `$3`.

Ref: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)